# How to remove this line

Tags: modeling

I want to deactivate the line that comes from the hair. Probably is it very simple but I don't even know the word in english.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

That black dotted line between objects indicates a "parent/child" relationship.
To disable the line display, turn off "Relationship Lines" in the "Object" section of the Overlays panel.

Comment: Okey, thank you!